# Laravel 5: Bulk insertion in mongo DB showing error

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I am using [jenssegers](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package in Laravel 5 for mongodb. 
I am inserting multiple data in below described way and data is inserted successfully in mongodb but then it through error before the script completes.

```
$AllTrans=array();
$AllTrans[]=array("InvoiceID"=>1,"Amount"=>50);
$AllTrans[]=array("InvoiceID"=>2,"Amount"=>150);

$mongo_connnection->collection('invoices')->insert($AllTrans);
```

Here is the error:

```
MongoException in Collection.php line 42: 
No write ops were included in the batch
```

But i can not figure out problem, I have tried passing option like   array('multi' => true) with insert query but it was not working.

Comment: Have you tried using the QueryBuilder's collection object `DB::collection('invoices')->insert($AllTrans);`?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple database connection in single website so i have taken connection in variable $mongo_connnection so it is same as DB::collection('invoices')

Comment: please check for the empty records, which gives error for empty record processing....

Comment: Please check if you have a unique index on field that you are not providing (null)

Answer (score -2):

It will work great with bulk addition, this way, you just need to create on array and pass it to it.

```
$temp = [
            [
                'item'=> "envelopes"
            ],
            [
                'item'=> "envelopesas"
            ],
            [
                'item'=> "lala"
            ]
        ];

        $userData = DB::table('log')->raw( function ( $collection ) use ($temp) {

            return $collection->insertMany($temp);
        });
```